# iText - add a fixed paragraph on the bottom of Document

Tags: java, itext

I'm using iText to generate a pdf file and after understanding that to set a paragraph on center you can use:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Content");
p.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
```

Which means that you manipulate the paragraph, and only the paragraph. But what if I would need to put the paragraph on the bottom of my page?
For example, my content anywhere else on the page can be short or long (like a form to fill), and despite every input, the paragraph will remain at the bottom untouchable. This would require the Document manipulation? 'Cause the way I see it's like if I'm creating a paragraph and telling the document that it should put the paragraph on it's bottom, not just create any paragraph and insert it after the next line. Thanks in advance for any comments

Answer (score 1):

Content can be added to a static location. This is adding the text to the coordinates 36, 650 in a rectangle that is 100 by 100. In a pdf 0, 0 is the bottom left corner.

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
PdfPage page = pdf.addNewPage();
PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(36, 650, 100, 100);
pdfCanvas.rectangle(rectangle);
pdfCanvas.stroke();
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdf, rectangle);
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.TIMES_ROMAN);
Text title = new Text("The Strange Case of Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde").setFont(font);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph().add(title);
canvas.add(p);
canvas.close();
pdf.close();
```

This example was taken from https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/itext-7-building-blocks-chapter-2-rootelement-examples